# Why ARel query is returned as ActiveRecord::Relation class instead of parent class?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have a class:

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base  
  scope :named, lambda {|name| where(["first_name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%"])}  
end
```

In rails console, when I do the following query:

```
technician = Technician.named("john")  
technician.class => ActiveRecord::Relation and not Technician
```

this matters because I get a no method error when I try to access the class attributes:

```
technician.id => no method error
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arel returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` so that it can defer the execution to the last moment and provide better composability.

`Technician.named("john").first` instead of `Technician.named("john")` to get the `technician`.

Comment: Chandra...thanks for your help.  It would have taken me forever to figure that nuance myself.